# Xcode 7 imports swift framework but "Expected declaration"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm having an issue with Xcode 7. A few days ago i've changed the Derived Data settings to be able to debug something made with Appcelerator Titanium.

Yesterday I wanted to create a new project and import Alamofire and SwiftifyJSON with pods and now carthage.

Nothing works. Xcode builds them, the frameworks are included in the project, but Xcode can't autocomplete and says "Expected Declaration". I tried setting the Derived Data back but no avail.

Right now the Derived Data is set to Default and Unique in advanced.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Mihai

[Xcode Framework Search Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2BuB.png)

[Xcode error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrI5E.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple answer:

All code to be executed must be in a method or function.
You have to put the `Alamofire` line in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Damn... And I lost 2 days trying to mess around with the Xcode settings... It works. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, very good and simple answer, which enables me to continuing work

Comment: Thanks, was on the verge of removing it. *NOTE:* like @vadian said, "All code to be executed must be in a method or function.", it doesn't **have** to be in `viewDidLoad`, any function will do.